# The value of $H^2(U(N), U(1))$

Tags: lie-groups, group-cohomology

I am interested to know $H^2(U(N), U(1))= ?$. Any reference or hints are welcome. Thanks a lot!

Comment: $H^2(G,U(1))$ classifies the central extensions of $G$ by $U(1)$. So ...

Comment: @DietrichBurde So $H^2(U(N), U(1))$ is trivial?